# osx bash command gives Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: bash, macos

when i open a new terminal window in OS X and just type bash, i got a segmentation fault:11 all the time.
The problem seems to be specific to my machine as i have tried it on another machine and it worked fine.
[bash gives out segfault 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bMi9.png)

Comment: Is it `bash` that crashes, or a program in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: After deleting .bashrc, everything works fine. It seems that "if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi" is causing the issue. Thank you!

Comment: the question is what what was there in ~/.bashrc

Comment: There's nothing except this "if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc fi" in the ~/.bashrc file and that was causing bash to crash.

Answer (score 4):

You had infinite recursion. When `bash` started, it executed `.bashrc`, which sources `.bashrc`, which sources `.bashrc`, etc. Eventually, you run out of memory somewhere, because `bash` has to remember where in the previous iteration of `.bashrc` it is so it can continue after the next one returns, which leads to the segmentation fault.

Comment: it happened to me when I create a function named `docker()` which uses the command docker inside it, so a recursion

Comment: This causes the recursion in my case:   
`if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi`   
How can it be helped?

Comment: Same thing: your `.bash_aliases` file is apparently trying to source (either directly or indirectly) the file that is sourcing `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: @chepner Found. Sourced local aliases under `root` with tilde variable, which is apparently recursive. Changed to explicit path. Many thanks for the hint!